Reinforcement learning with Q learning doesn't seem to be learning
I'm encountering an issue with my PyTorch-based Q-learning model. Despite implementing the reinforcement learning algorithm, the model seems to be stuck at the same balance level without showing any improvement over time. It continues to make trades, but the overall balance remains stagnant. I'm unsure why this behavior is occurring and how to rectify it. Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and enhance the model's learning process would be greatly appreciated

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import deque
import random
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

df = pd.read_feather('ETH_USDT-30m.feather')
name = 'Q-learning agent'

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

def calculate_profit_loss(position, entry_price, exit_price, balance):
    if entry_price > 0 and exit_price > 0:
        if position == 'Long':
            profit_loss = (balance/entry_price) * exit_price
            profit_loss -= balance
        elif position == 'Short':
            profit_loss = (balance/exit_price) * entry_price
            profit_loss -= balance
        else:
            profit_loss = 0
            
        print(position, entry_price, exit_price, balance + profit_loss - ((balance*6)/10000))
    
        return balance + profit_loss - ((balance*6)/10000)

class Agent:
    def __init__(self, state_size, window_size, trend, skip, batch_size):
        self.state_size = state_size
        self.window_size = window_size
        self.half_window = window_size // 2
        self.trend = trend
        self.skip = skip
        self.action_size = 3
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.memory = deque(maxlen=10000)
        self.inventory = []
        self.gamma = 0.95
        self.epsilon = 0.5
        self.epsilon_min = 0.01
        self.epsilon_decay = 0.999
        self.model = self._build_model().to(device)
        self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr=1e-5)
        self.criterion = nn.MSELoss()

    def _build_model(self):
        model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(self.state_size, 256),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(256, self.action_size)
        )
        return model

    def act(self, state):
        if random.random() <= self.epsilon:
            return random.randrange(self.action_size)
        state = torch.FloatTensor(np.array(state)).to(device)
        with torch.no_grad():
            q_values = self.model(state)
        return torch.argmax(q_values).item()

    def get_state(self, t):
        window_size = self.window_size + 1
        d = t - window_size + 1
        block = self.trend[d: t + 1] if d >= 0 else -d * [self.trend[0]] + self.trend[0: t + 1]
        res = []
        for i in range(window_size - 1):
            res.append(block[i + 1] - block[i])
        return np.array([res])

    def replay(self, batch_size):
        mini_batch = random.sample(self.memory, batch_size)
        replay_size = len(mini_batch)
        states = np.array([a[0] for a in mini_batch])
        new_states = np.array([a[3] for a in mini_batch])
        states = torch.FloatTensor(np.array(states)).to(device)
        new_states = torch.FloatTensor(np.array(new_states)).to(device)
        Q = self.model(states).view(replay_size, -1)  
        Q_new = self.model(new_states).view(replay_size, -1) 
        X = []
        Y = []

        for i in range(replay_size):
            state, action, reward, next_state, done = mini_batch[i]
            target = Q[i].clone().detach()

            if action >= self.action_size or action < 0:
                print(f"Action index out of bounds: {action}")
                continue

            target[action] = reward
            if not done:
                target[action] += self.gamma * torch.max(Q_new[i]).item()
            X.append(state)
            Y.append(target.cpu().numpy())

        X = torch.FloatTensor(np.array(X)).to(device).view(replay_size, -1) 
        Y = torch.FloatTensor(np.array(Y)).to(device).view(replay_size, -1)  

        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = self.model(X)
        loss = self.criterion(outputs, Y)
        loss.backward()
        self.optimizer.step()
        
        if self.epsilon > self.epsilon_min:
            self.epsilon *= self.epsilon_decay
        return loss.item()

    def train(self, iterations, checkpoint, initial_money):
        for i in range(iterations):
            total_profit = 0
            inventory = []
            state = self.get_state(0)
            starting_money = 10000
            temp = 10000
            self.consecutive_no_trades = 0
            holding_position = 0
            kosulsaglanmadi = True
            self.bought_price = 0 
            self.last_action = "noriziski"
            for t in range(0, len(self.trend) - 1, self.skip):
                action = self.act(state)
                next_state = self.get_state(t + 1)
                
                # Check if the threshold for waiting is reached
                if self.consecutive_no_trades >= 7:
                    if kosulsaglanmadi:
                        reward = 0.1 #action = 0  # Wait
                        kosulsaglanmadi = False
                    
                else:
                    kosulsaglanmadi = True
                    reward = 0

                if action == 1 and self.last_action == 2 or self.last_action == "noriziski":
                    self.last_action = action
                    inventory.append(self.trend[t])
                    if self.bought_price == 0:
                        self.bought_price = inventory.pop(0)
                    else:                       
                        temp = starting_money 
                        starting_money = calculate_profit_loss('Short', self.bought_price, self.trend[t], initial_money)
                        self.bought_price = inventory.pop(0)
                        
                elif action == 2 and self.last_action == 1 or self.last_action == "noriziski":
                    self.last_action = action
                    inventory.append(self.trend[t])
                    if self.bought_price == 0:
                        self.bought_price = inventory.pop(0)
                    else:                       
                        temp = starting_money 
                        starting_money = calculate_profit_loss('Long', self.bought_price, self.trend[t], initial_money)
                        self.bought_price = inventory.pop(0)
                else:
                    self.consecutive_no_trades += 1 
                
                if starting_money > temp:
                    zowski = 0.1
                    
                else:
                    zowski = 0
                
                invest = ((starting_money - temp) / temp)*350 + zowski + reward 
                self.memory.append((state, action, invest, next_state, len(inventory) > 0))

                state = next_state
                batch_size = min(self.batch_size, len(self.memory))
                cost = self.replay(batch_size)

            if (i + 1) % checkpoint == 0:
                print(f'Epoch: {i + 1}, Total Rewards: {total_profit:.3f}, Cost: {cost:.6f}, Total Money: {starting_money}, Epsilon: {self.epsilon:.5f}')
                
close = df['close'].values.tolist()
initial_money = 10000
window_size = 30
skip = 1
batch_size = 32
agent = Agent(state_size=window_size, window_size=window_size, trend=close, skip=skip, batch_size=batch_size)
agent.train(iterations=2000, checkpoint=1, initial_money=initial_money)

Output:
Short 3508.59 3526.05 9944.482834900242
Long 3526.05 3540.25 10034.271692120077
Short 3540.25 3517.57 10058.476328829276
Long 3517.57 3534.2 10041.276955398185
Short 3534.2 3560.26 9920.803098650096
Long 3560.26 3541.98 9942.655435277198
Short 3541.98 3554.23 9959.53402565394
Long 3554.23 3519.85 9897.270187916933
Short 3519.85 3546.43 9919.051389707396
Long 3546.43 3529.52 9946.318246800305
Short 3529.52 3522.39 10014.241938002322
Long 3522.39 3430.85 9734.119634679862
Short 3430.85 3503.01 9788.005726503778
Long 3503.01 3483.2 9937.448634174609
Short 3483.2 3478.02 10008.893531377047
Long 3478.02 3501.45 10061.365915089618
Short 3501.45 3522.24 9934.975061324612
Long 3522.24 3511.4 9963.22413009903
Short 3511.4 3483.0 10075.538903244329
Long 3483.0 3466.49 9946.598334768876
Short 3466.49 3437.0 10079.80157113762
Long 3437.0 3433.01 9982.391038696538
Short 3433.01 3434.12 9990.767730888847
Long 3434.12 3405.19 9909.757166319174
Short 3405.19 3408.88 9983.175330313768
Long 3408.88 3340.35 9792.966229377389
Short 3340.35 3349.31 9967.248221275428
Long 3349.31 3312.79 9884.962616180646
Short 3312.79 3328.15 9947.848234003875
Long 3328.15 3340.46 10030.987515586738
Short 3340.46 3317.49 10063.239093410983
Long 3317.49 3288.07 9905.318496815364
Short 3288.07 3287.2 9996.646629350207
Long 3287.2 3309.82 10062.812363105379
Short 3309.82 3336.79 9913.173816752029
Long 3336.79 3338.59 9999.394406000976
Short 3338.59 3326.12 10031.491130807066

No matter how much it trains, balance always staying at the almost same level without an improving
